# Fixing Unicode issues on Windows 7

Tags: css, windows, unicode, windows-7

I have library that renders ANSI art [ansidec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansidec). And I have problem rendering on Windows 7 (all browser because of Unicode bugs).

Here is Demo:

https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/ZVdJOd

I have code like this to fix issue that some characters are wider then `m` and taller then line-height:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var format_ansi = ansi.format(function(styles, color, background, text) {
    var style = [];
    if (color) {
        style.push('color:' + color);
    }
    if (background) {
        style.push('background:' + background);
    }
    if (styles.bold) {
        style.push('font-weight:bold');
    }
    if (styles.italic) {
        style.push('font-style:italic');
    }
    if (styles.underline) {
        styles.push('text-decoration:underline');
    }
    text = Array.from(text).map(function(chr) {
        return '<span class="chr">' + chr + '</span>';
    }).join('');
    return '<span style="' + style.join(';') + '">' + text + '</span>';
});
function format(str) {
    output.innerHTML = format_ansi(str);
}
var url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jcubic/ansidec@master/example/unix.ans';
fetch(url).then((res) => res.text()).then(format);
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        format(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
});
```

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.chr {
    max-width: 1ch;
    overflow: hidden;
}
pre {
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<pre id="output" style="background: black"></pre>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ansidec@0.2.1/dist/ascidec.min.js"></script>
```

I'm wrapping every character in span and set max-width (it if course will not work correctly on IE because of ch unit bug).

the problem is black space in top of the graphic (black space below second line from top) and white line below nose that is not on Linux.

[image: Denis Ritchie ANSI art on Windows 7]

It's almost the same as on GNU/Linux, the line is little taller. I only want to know why that black space and that white line and how to fix them (Tested on Chrome/Windows 7).

[image: Denis Ritchie ANSI art on GNU/Linux]

I've tried to set `overflow: hidden;` on span that this give black spaces for each line, and is still happen if I remove `line-height`. How can make it looks the same on Windows 7 as on Linux? Is this possible?

And if I set display: inline the black spaces disappear but width don't longer works.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a "Unicode issue" -- that implies there is some encoding problem. What you're actually describing is a browser element height problem?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart this is unicode issue on Windows 7 the characters don't look correctly, they fixed that in Windows 10 I need workaround.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart another example of broken Unicode in Windows <10 https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/oMYbRG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed the issue I've wrapped each line in div:

```
function format(str) {
    output.innerHTML = format_ansi(str).split(/\n/).map(function(line) {
        return '<div>' + line + '</div>';
    }).join('')
}
```

and added this css:

```
div {
    max-height: 1em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/ZVdJOd